# DyanmoDB primary key design: one of the most frequent operation is "list items by time order", should I use timestamp?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

**Edit: @notionquest reminded commented that DynamoDB's primary key is a hash-key, so my idea described below won't work; but I still would like to discuss how to achieve this "order by time" feature during DynamoDB schema design**

**Here I found AWS uses DynamoDB to serve its forum, see [AWS DynamoDB Example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AppendixSampleTables.html#AppendixSampleData.Thread). How does AWS Forum display the thread by time order?**

I have a DynamoDB table `Tweet Items`, and my webapp's landing page is to show Tweet Items in chronicle order (Note: a 'Tweet' is my own webapp's data, not a Tweet from Twitter.com -- I use Tweet here to describe the situation of this question clear enough)

Apparently, the most frequent query (every user's homepage will need this query) to my DynamoDB is to list all the tweets stored in my `Tweet Items` table.

It is tempting to have the following table structure

```
| primary  Key             | Attribute  |
| Timestamp                | text-content|
-------------------------------------------
| "2017-03-05-12:30:30"    | "some string"|
```

But I also hear that it is normally an anti-pattern to have timestamp as hash key.

For my use case, is it wise for me to use timestamp as primary key? If not, what should I do?

Comment: How are you ordering the data in chronological order? I believe hash key doesn't help in that regard.

Comment: Sorry, corrected from 'hash' to 'primary' --I meant primary key

Comment: In DynamoDB, primary key is nothing but Hash key or Partition key. The term primary key is RDBMS term. Please note that there is no ORDER BY feature available on DynamoDB. That's why I asked how are you sorting the data by chronological order.

Answer (score 1):

It seems straight forward that you can use `timestamp` as the `sort` key instead of the hash key.  You will need something else to serve as the hashkey, the "tweet" id if you have it.  If you don't have an id you can use a generated value.

Then you can use [ScanIndexForward](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-ScanIndexForward) to control whether the timestamps are returned in ascending or descending order.

Comment: Jim, what do you meant by 'sort key'? Is that a partition key or a range key or something else in AWS DynamoDB's term http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html?

Comment: Sort and range keys are the same thing.  Some docs/ui use one term, some the other.